# Determine aws region inside a aws glue job

Tags: aws-glue, aws-regions

Hello I need some help in determining aws region inside a glue job.
I am trying to use boto3 client kms and when I do the following I get a Error 
`NoRegionError: You must specify a region.`
`kms  = boto3.client('kms')`
Obviously it is asking me to set region_name when creating the client but I do not wish to hardcode the region

When running a glue job i do see a line in the logs which says `Detected region us-east-2` but I am not sure on how I can fetch that value ?

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37514810/how-to-get-the-region-of-the-current-user-from-boto) answer already? Most AWS services set up the environment appropriately, to make sure this works.

Comment: Thanks Maurice! Yes I tried the above link but that returns me None.

Answer (score 3):

If you're running Pyspark / Python shell Glue job, try this:

```
import requests

r = requests.get("http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document")
response_json = r.json()
region = response_json.get('region')

print region
```

Comment: Wow, at first I thought there's no way this black magic works... but  alas it's an AWS thing: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-identity-documents.html

Comment: You can also access it from the environment variable if you are on Glue 2.0+: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72467100/6580142

Answer (score -1):

AWS Glue is still not available in all the regions. You may refer this [link](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/03/aws-glue-is-now-available-in-the-asia-pacific-sydney-and-eu-frankfurt-aws-regions/)

That's the reason you need to hardcode the region.

Coming to the "Detected region us-east-2" this might be becus of your aws CLI configuration

Comment: Sorry I did not follow the aws CLI configuration part. I am running the above code in AWS Glue as a Spark JOB not locally.

Comment: While creating the Job, you must have selected the region.. I don't think it's required to set the region specifically in the program

Comment: If the job while executing creates an AWS client to access some other resource, the region needs to be specified.